# Can't use useLocation() in react-router 5

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I made an simple taskshceduler with react router 5 and react redux and work fine still.

Now I try animating between different route with react-transition-group.

For this i need the useLocation that i can pass this result to the CSSTransition.

So the TransitionGroup can sense it and remove the page from the DOM for the right time.

But if I only initialize useLoaction from react-router-dom >> const location = useLocation();

I get error

What is the problem and What is the solution?

Thank you

App.js

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Notification from "./shared/UIElements/Notification";
import { sendCartData, fetchCartData } from "./store/cart-actions";
import Auth from "./Auth/page/Auth";
import TaskMain from "./tasks/page/TaskMain";
import TaskFilter from "./tasks/page/TaskFilter";
import MainNavigation from "./Layout/Navigation/MainNavigation";
import LoadingSpinner from "./shared/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import CSSTransition from "react-transition-group/CSSTransition";
import "../src/scss/styles.css";

import UpdateTask from "./tasks/page/UpdateTask";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NewTask from "./tasks/page/NewTask";

let isInitial = true;

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);
  const logged = useSelector((state) => state.cart.logged);
  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM ROW:
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCartData());
    console.log(`fetch usefeect`);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }

    if (cart.changed) {
      dispatch(sendCartData(cart));
    }
  }, [cart, dispatch]);

  let routes;
  if (!logged) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Auth />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <TaskMain />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tasks/new" exact>
          <NewTask />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tasks/update/:id" exact>
          <UpdateTask />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/items" exact>
          <TaskFilter />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        {notification && (
          <Notification
            status={notification.status}
            title={notification.title}
            message={notification.message}
          />
        )}
        <MainNavigation />
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
          timeout={250}
          classNames='fade'
          >
            <Suspense
              fallback={
                <div className="center">
                  <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
                </div>
              }
            >
              {routes}
            </Suspense>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error:

```
hooks.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
    at useLocation (hooks.js:29:1)
    at App (App.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021:1
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431:1)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020:1)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:8:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (UpdateTask.js:8:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:93
useLocation @ hooks.js:29
App @ App.js:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ UpdateTask.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:191:83)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37458:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ UpdateTask.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
hooks.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
    at useLocation (hooks.js:29:1)
    at App (App.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021:1
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431:1)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020:1)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:8:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (UpdateTask.js:8:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:93
useLocation @ hooks.js:29
App @ App.js:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ UpdateTask.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/config.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/content.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/config.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/content.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
VM173:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (index.js:1:1)
```

Package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.4.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

Comment: ^ Different hook. Same problem. Your router is a child of the component you're trying to use the hook in. This means the contexts is not available to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to use router context outside of `Router`. You should separate components, so `useLocation` will be used only in component, that is nested to `Router`.